# How to bulk increment a unique IntegerField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I bulk increment an **`IntegerField`** that has a unique constraint?

For example:

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    level = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

>> Rank.objects.create(level=1)
>> Rank.objects.create(level=2)
>> Rank.objects.create(level=3)

>> Rank.objects.all().update(level=F('level')+1)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'myapp_rank.level'")
```

The following query works fine in MySQL (assuming `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0`):

```
UPDATE myapp_rank t SET t.rank = t.rank + 1;
```

Is there a way to do this using the ORM?

Comment: The problem is that when for example rank object with level one gets incremented by 1 and becomes 2 then it is duplicate with rank object with level 2?

Comment: Same problem here. I tried ordering the queryset so that it would start with the highest rank, but to no avail. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @gabn88 I never did, sorry.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I have raised a Django Ticket regarding support for ORDER BY on MySQL (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31573#ticket and https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql/issues/654). For other databases  I think a deferred unique field is the way to go forward. Thanks for getting back to me!